# tensorflow gradient with repect to a subset of trainable variables

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to take the gradient of the loss function just with respect to a single weight in a layer. For taking the derivative with respect to the entire first layer, the following works fine

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
g = tape.gradient(loss(y, model(X)), model.trainable_variables[0])
```

However I would like to do something like

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
g = tape.gradient(loss(y, y_pred), model.trainable_variables[0][:1])
```

but this returns None. I think accessing the variable sets it to a value and thus the derivative with respect to it is None. Is there some way to take the derivative with respect to a slice of a layers variables?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible, see [issue here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22059).

Unfortunately, and there does not seem to be anything to do about it.